# how to get indexpath of tableView in any method

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to show animation if the indexPath == 0 and scroll direction is downward, but I'm unable to get the indexPath of tableView in scrollViewdidScroll method. here's my code -->

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: ThirdTableViewCell() as UITableViewCell)
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) && indexPath?.row == 0  {
        print ("up")
    }
    else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y)  {
     //   print ("down")
    }

    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

I got the indexPath nil while debugging

Comment: You get `nil` because you are passing in a cell you just created. That cell isn't visible in the tableview and doesn't have an associated index path.

Comment: @Paulw11 what is the right method ?

Comment: You might be able to use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614874-indexpathforrow) in conjunction with the scroll view offset

Comment: What do you mean by *"if the indexPath == 0 and scroll direction is downward"*? Do you mean you want to do something when the user scrolls through your table, and then drags down and the top row becomes visible again?

Comment: @DonMag i want indexPath == 0 and and user scrool down i just want to show a down arrow annimation on first row of tableview

Comment: @xahiw - that's still not clear. Do you want this "down arrow animation" to be *inside* the first cell/row? Or is it ***not*** part of a cell, and you want it shown/animated whenever the row at `indexPath == 0` is visible?

Comment: I just show the arrow when these two conditions is fulfill otherwise arrow.ishidden = true in viewdidload method

Comment: You can get the first cell by creating an indexPath with `let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)` and then using `let cell = cellForItem(at: indexPath)`. After you retrieve the cell, type cast it and then unhide the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't explained what you really want to do, but maybe this will help...

Start by setting up your `scrollViewDidScroll` like this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    var partOfRowZeroIsVisible: Bool = false
    var topOfRowZeroIsVisible: Bool = false
    var userIsDraggingDown: Bool = false

    // if user pulls table DOWN when Row Zero is at top,
    //  contentOffset.y will be negative and table will
    //  bounce back up...
    // so, we make y AT LEAST 0.0
    let y = max(0.0, tableView.contentOffset.y)
    
    // point for the top visible content
    let pt: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: y)
    
    if let idx = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: pt), idx.row == 0 {
        // At least PART of Row Zero is visible...
        partOfRowZeroIsVisible = true
    } else {
        // Row Zero is NOT visible...
        partOfRowZeroIsVisible = false
    }
    
    if y == 0 {
        // Table view is scrolled all the way to the top...
        topOfRowZeroIsVisible = true
    } else {
        // Table view is NOT scrolled all the way to the top...
        topOfRowZeroIsVisible = false
    }
    
    if (self.lastContentOffset >= y) {
        // User is DRAGGING the table DOWN
        userIsDraggingDown = true
    } else {
        // User is DRAGGING the table UP
        userIsDraggingDown = false
    }

    // save current offset
    self.lastContentOffset = y
```

Then, to show or hide your "arrow":

```
    // if you want to show your "arrow"
    //  when ANY PART of Row Zero is visible
    if partOfRowZeroIsVisible {
        arrow.isHidden = false
    } else {
        arrow.isHidden = true
    }
```

or:

```
    // if you want to show your "arrow"
    //  ONLY when table view has been scrolled ALL THE WAY to the top
    if topOfRowZeroIsVisible {
        arrow.isHidden = false
    } else {
        arrow.isHidden = true
    }
```

or:

```
    // if you want to show your "arrow"
    //  when ANY PART of Row Zero is visible
    //  and
    //  ONLY if the user is dragging DOWN
    if partOfRowZeroIsVisible && userIsDraggingDown {
        arrow.isHidden = false
    } else {
        arrow.isHidden = true
    }
```

or:

```
    // if you want to show your "arrow"
    //  ONLY when table view has been scrolled ALL THE WAY to the top
    //  and
    //  ONLY if the user is dragging DOWN
    if topOfRowZeroIsVisible && userIsDraggingDown {
        arrow.isHidden = false
    } else {
        arrow.isHidden = true
    }
```